# Does the RouteRule name matter?

Tags: apigee

I am tring to understand Apigee RouteRule (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/understanding-routes?hl=lv)

```
<RouteRule name="MyRoute">
   <Condition>request.header.routeTo = "TargetEndpoint1"</Condition>
   <TargetEndpoint>TargetEndpoint1</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="default">
   <TargetEndpoint>TargetEndpoint2</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

My question is that if I change the rule name, does it matter?

For example, I change `MyRoute` to `YourRoute`, then it becomes

```
<RouteRule name="YourRoute">
   <Condition>request.header.routeTo = "TargetEndpoint1"</Condition>
   <TargetEndpoint>TargetEndpoint1</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="default">
   <TargetEndpoint>TargetEndpoint2</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

I can't find the route rule name is referenced in the other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the  is just the name you have given to your RouteRule policy. There can be multiple Route rules and therefore to distinguish it and for our convenience. The policy names are not referenced anywhere they are just included in the proxy flow xml. It is very similar to  or . Till it is being added into the proxy flow, it will be executed.